# C# Pattern Matching using Templated Type

Tags: c#, switch-statement

How can I rewrite this method using a pattern-matching switch?

```
internal ResultType Fetch<ResultType>(string field)
{
    var type = typeof(ResultType);
    object xx = type switch
    {
        _ when type == typeof(DateTime) => FetchDateTime(field),
        _ when type == typeof(DateOnly) => FetchDateOnly(field),
        _ when type == typeof(bool) => FetchBool(field),
        _ when type == typeof(decimal) => FetchDecimal(field),
        _ when type == typeof(string) => FetchString(field),
        _ when type == typeof(int) => FetchInt(field),

        _ => throw new NotImplementedException($"this[field: {field}]")
    };

    if (xx is ResultType rt) return rt;
    return default(ResultType)!;
}
```

Comment: [You don't, sadly](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/356)

Comment: @canton7, can it, as a minimum, be simplified? It looks so bad!

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>>`?

Comment: The type of the generic type parameter is deterministic, and using switch in this case is not necessary because when you call this method (e.g. `Fetch<bool>(field)`), you already know what the type of `ResultType` is, which means you can directly call the corresponding `FetchBool` method.

Comment: `var fetch = (object xx) => type switch { typeof (int) => FetchInt }; return fetch(field);` can clean this up a bit. I think @Sweeper provides an excellent alternative. Dispatch dictionaries are very expressive

Answer (score 2):

Posting as an answer because the code is too long for a comment.

You can certainly make this more efficient (ignoring the length aspect). The JIT recognises the pattern `if (type == typeof(DateTime))` etc, and will emit code which keeps just the relevant parts of the method for a given `ResultType`.

For instance, your code results in the following when `ResultType` is `DateTime`:

```
C.Fetch[[System.DateTime, System.Private.CoreLib]](System.String)
    L0000: push ebp
    L0001: mov ebp, esp
    L0003: push esi
    L0004: sub esp, 8
    L0007: mov esi, edx
    L0009: mov ecx, 0x6e099a4
    L000e: call 0x060a300c
    L0013: lea edx, [eax+4]
    L0016: xor ecx, ecx
    L0018: mov [edx], ecx
    L001a: mov [edx+4], ecx
    L001d: mov edx, eax
    L001f: test edx, edx
    L0021: je short L002b
    L0023: cmp dword ptr [edx], 0x6e099a4
    L0029: je short L003a
    L002b: xor eax, eax
    L002d: mov [esi], eax
    L002f: mov [esi+4], eax
    L0032: lea esp, [ebp-4]
    L0035: pop esi
    L0036: pop ebp
    L0037: ret 4
    L003a: add eax, 4
    L003d: mov edx, [eax]
    L003f: mov eax, [eax+4]
    L0042: mov [ebp-0xc], edx
    L0045: mov [ebp-8], eax
    L0048: mov eax, esi
    L004a: mov edx, [ebp-0xc]
    L004d: mov [eax], edx
    L004f: mov edx, [ebp-8]
    L0052: mov [eax+4], edx
    L0055: lea esp, [ebp-4]
    L0058: pop esi
    L0059: pop ebp
    L005a: ret 4
```

However the code:

```
internal ResultType Fetch2<ResultType>(string field)
{
    var type = typeof(ResultType);
    if (type == typeof(DateTime))
    {
        return (ResultType)(object)FetchDateTime(field);
    }
    if (type == typeof(DateOnly))
    {
        return (ResultType)(object)FetchDateOnly(field);
    }
    throw new NotImplementedException($"this[field: {field}]");
}
```

Results in:

```
C.Fetch2[[System.DateTime, System.Private.CoreLib]](System.String)
    L0000: push ebp
    L0001: mov ebp, esp
    L0003: xor eax, eax
    L0005: mov [edx], eax
    L0007: mov [edx+4], eax
    L000a: pop ebp
    L000b: ret 4
```

This is the pattern that the runtime uses.

[See on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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).

Answer (score 1):

As canton7's answer said, it is more efficient at runtime if you check `ResultType` against other types using `==`, as that is what the JIT looks out for and optimises.

If you don't care about that, you can make your code "look prettier" by using a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>> dict = new()
{
    { typeof(DateTime), Wrap(FetchDateTime) },
    { typeof(string), FetchString },
    // and so on
};
```

Here I am assuming that the `FetchXXX` methods have the appropriate return type based on their name. Note that since value types don't do covariance, you need an extra `Wrap` helper to box the return values. Use this for the `FetchXXX` methods that return value types.

```
Func<string, object> Wrap<R>(Func<string, R> f) where R: struct 
    => x => f(x);
```

Then you can use this dictionary like this:

```
ResultType Fetch<ResultType>(string field)
{
    if (dict.TryGetValue(typeof(ResultType), out var f))
    {
        var result = f(field);
        return result is ResultType r ? r : default;
    } 
    else
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException($"this[field: {field}]");
    }
}
```

---

As a side note, if all the types that you are checking against are value types, you can actually use a pattern-matching `switch`, though this is *very* hacky. You would switch on `default(ResultType)`.

```
ResultType Fetch<ResultType>(string field) where ResultType: struct
{
    object xx = default(ResultType) switch
    {
        DateTime => FetchDateTime(field),
        DateOnly => FetchDateOnly(field),
        bool => FetchBool(field),
        decimal => FetchDecimal(field),
        int => FetchInt(field),
        _ => throw new NotImplementedException($"this[field: {field}]")
    };

    if (xx is ResultType rt) return rt;
    return default(ResultType)!;
}
```